# Resposta -1 deletada, retorna pontos gastos ao negativar?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Se eu marco uma resposta com **-1** por exemplo, caso o autor da mesma a delete, minha pontuação gasta ao marca-la como **-1** retorna, assim como ele recupera seus pontos negativados?

Comment: Não entendo, a gente não perde nada ao fazer `-1` numa Pergunta. Isso acontece com Respostas.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun, meu comentário se referia á [primeira versão da pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/1493/revisions). Acho melhor apagá-lo pra não gerar mais mal-entendidos. Amanhã apagarei meus comentários, sugiro o mesmo pra você. Valeu pelo feedback nonetheless, gracias!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, todo ganho/perda de reputação é desfeita (acho que seria mais preciso dizer: desconsiderada) quando uma publicação (pergunta ou resposta) é excluída. Se a mesma for restaurada, os votos voltam a ser considerados no cálculo.

Comment: Antes que alguém diga "mas não voltou": a restituição geralmente leva alguns minutos para ocorrer.