# Por que os pontos não voltam quando a pergunta é deletada?

Tags: debate

Quando uma pergunta é votada negativamente, creio que exista duas alternativas para o autor, ou ele edita e melhora a pergunta ou ele deleta a pergunta.

Imaginem que o autor fez diversas edições na pergunta e mesmo assim não conseguiu convencer os outros usuários a darem votos positivos para o sua pergunta e assim resolve deletá-la.

Os pontos que o autor perdeu com aquela pergunta não deveriam retornar? Já que ele deletou a postagem negativada?.

Porque os pontos perdidos com aquela pergunta por causa dos *down votes* não são recuperados?

Imagino que a atitude de deletar perguntas negativadas seja uma boa iniciativa, já que ao perceber que a sua pergunta não foi bem aceita pela comunidade, nada mais digno que o próprio autor reconheça e faça a remoção.

Dessa forma o autor consegue perceber que a pergunta ou resposta feita por ele está causando a si mesmo mais prejuízo do que benefício(em relação a sua pontuação total).

No meu caso, a primeira vez os pontos retornaram mas na segunda postagem que eu apaguei, os pontos não retornaram.

No [caso dessa pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1493/69614) a resposta foi diferente

Comment: *Imagino que a atitude de deletar perguntas negativadas seja uma boa iniciativa* **NÃO!** Procure sempre melhorar a pergunta pedindo sugestões nos comentários ou debate-la aqui no meta. Se você ficar deletando as perguntas o sistema pode aplicar uma punição e você será impedido de fazer novas perguntas até que sua conduta no site seja melhorada através de boas contribuições.

Comment: Ficou confusa a sua afirmação, Se o sistema bloquear um usuário por má conduta, impedindo que ele faça novas perguntas, como ele vai poder contribuir? será somente com respostas a outras perguntas já existentes?

Comment: Existe outras formas de contribuir com o site alem de fazer perguntas, pode ser editando post, sinalizando, votando ou participando do meta. Não sei o certo qual seria o critério de contribuição correto que o sistema usa para remover a punição, mas estes que eu citei já dever ser o suficiente.

Comment: "exista duas alternativas", não só existe uma, editar e melhorar.

Comment: Normalmente, todas as alterações à reputação dos utilizadores envolvidos com uma publicação são revertidas se esta for apagada. Há umas quantas excepções, no entanto. Estamos a falar de algum caso em particular aqui?

Comment: O caso específico ocorreu comigo mesmo, eu imaginava que os pontos retornavam, mas ao apagar algumas publicações negativadas eu me dei conta que os pontos não voltaram. =(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na verdade é o oposto, isto significa que a pessoa causou ruído na comunidade. Não só os pontos não voltam como na verdade ela vai cavando o buraco para ter a capacidade de postar novas perguntas revogada.

A intenção do sistema é fazer as pessoas não criarem problemas para a comunidade. Não pode incentivar ela a postar qualquer porcaria e fazer de conta que nada aconteceu. Ela tem que se responsabilizar pelo que faz. Esta é uma das coisas que mais gosto do sistema. As pessoas precisam aprender a se responsabilizar.

A única solução para algo ruim é consertar. Se der um prêmio para ela remover a pergunta ela continuará fazendo perguntas ruins.

Comment: Realmente não sabia que deletar perguntas ou respostas fosse danoso ao sistema e principalmente ao autor, agradeço pela resposta. Aparentemente a minhas afirmação era um falso positivo.