# O SOpt emite algum alerta a respeito de conduta inadequada?

Tags: debate

Há algum tempo perguntei [sobre má conduta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6590/69614) no meta e para minha surpresa, aprendi que se um usuário deleta perguntas feitas ao invés de melhora-la, o sistema irá punir o usuário a ponto de negar sua permissão de fazer novas perguntas.

Dado o contexto, gostaria de saber, quantas vezes um usuário pode apagar perguntas mal feitas, a ponto de não ser punido? Existe algum tipo de alerta do SOpt para que o usuário seja avisado antes de ser punido de fato?

Comment: Há uma forma fácil de não descobrir, não apague conteúdo e tente sempre melhorar o mesmo. :)

Comment: O ideal é não fazer, independente do limite, o objetivo do site é sermos construtivos, qualquer atitude fora disto (por exemplo, tentar andar nos limites da "lei") para mim soa com um possível egoísmo.

Answer (score 11):

Eu também gostaria de saber, e olha que eu sou moderador do site :)

O fato é que os fatores exatos que levam aos bloqueios – e desbloqueios – automáticos do sistema não são divulgados, para não facilitar para quem estiver tentando burlá-los. É um pouco draconiano mesmo, mas em geral melhorias no conteúdo já postado costumam desbloquear a conta (só reverter exclusão não basta).

Sobre avisos, sei que o sistema emite alguns sim, mas não sei listar exatamente (quem souber edita aqui ou deixa nos comentários). Por exemplo, se você tem edições sugeridas recentes rejeitadas, o sistema avisa ao tentar editar uma pergunta. Deve haver outros alertas do tipo, mas duvido que algo muito específico para não entregar como funciona o algoritmo de bloqueio.

Comment: Eu recebi um flag por acho que por conteúdo ofensivo e recebi uma pena de dois pontos sem maiores explicações. Conta como uma espécie de alerta?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim. Se você receber muitos desses, você pode ser bloqueado. Porém, acho estranho que tenha recebido isso. Dado o comportamento de cada um eu esperava avisos assim para mim, mas não para você (acompanho vários de seus posts).

Answer (score 3):

O sistema não avisa utilizadores que estão prestes a apagar publicações sobre se esse acto vai causar um bloqueio. Mas, geralmente, se utilizador se encontrar nessa condição, significa que provavelmente já tem muitas publicações de fraca qualidade — e em relação a essas, [o sistema avisa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/208518)!

Se um utilizador tiver feito perguntas mal-recebidas pela comunidade recentemente, quando este está prestes a publicar, vai ver esta mensagem (presumivelmente, em português):

> [image: aviso perguntas]

ou em respostas:

> [image: aviso resposta]

Comment: Aqui no SOpt, essas mensagens estão traduzidas como? É possível obter um screenshot delas sem ter que criar um sockpuppet que faça lambanças de propósito?

Comment: Imagino que tenham sido traduzidas no Transifex. Como não tenho acesso a estas, não consigo fornecer a tradução exacta. E também não tenho um screenshot à mão.